# Ckeditor5 is not found after installing it throug npm and compiling throug laravel mix

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, laravel-mix, ckeditor5

I have installed ckeditor5 using npm in my laravel 5.6 project ( `npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic`) then i added `window.ckeditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');`
 to my `resources/assets/js/app.js` and ran `npm run dev`.The compilation was successfull.
In my view when i try to  reference `ckeditor`, it says it cannot find ckeditor. please help

here is my `resources/assets/js/app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/* tried both of these options one by one*/
window.ckeditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');
// import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";`

[Installing Instructions](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/basic-api.html#umd-support)

Comment: can you share your app.js content?

Comment: how can i share?

Comment: just add it in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
const ClassicEditor = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' );
```